# Is there any way to set a quota for number of API calls to the org?

Tags: integration, connected-apps

Is there any best practice or configs available to set API call quotas per Connected App so that Salesforce API call limit isn't exceeded?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can run reports and determine which clients are using the most resources, but there is no way to enforce quotas to prevent this from happening. Note that API usage limits roll off hourly, so fixing/blocking an offending client will ensure that your org isn't down for very long.

Comment: Is there a way to block API Connected Apps from APEX when they reach certain point. For example scheduled job that checks api usage hourly?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a "quota" on the client (caller) side by looking at `Sforce-Limit-Info` header that is included by SF in REST and SOAP API responses. From [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_api_usage.htm):

> Field values
>
> api-usage — Specifies the API usage for the organization
> against which the call was made in the format nn/nnnn. The first
> number is the number of API calls used, and the second number is the
> API limit for the organization

Comment: I need to implement it on Salesforce side so it would be used generally for all connected apps